# How can I launch the correct version of gradle from any sub-project directory?

Tags: bash, function, gradle, alias

So the idea is that no matter which sub-project I'm in and no matter which SCM project check-out I'm working on, I want to launch the correct wrapper version of Gradle.

For example if I have a project A that has two sub-projects B and C, I should be able to be in either B or C and get the correct version of the gradle wrapper in project A. ...but wait. There's more. ;-)

It also needs to work on project Q, which I've just checked out, which has sub-project's Z and Y. In other words, I don't want to get Project A's wrapper if I'm working in Y. I want project Q's version.

I have a BASH function (you can use it just like an alias) for this but I'm willing to hand the points to anyone who has one that is equal to or better than. If not, I'll post mine as the answer.

Comment: Would you mind to include your bash function here?

Comment: @ferdy [find-gradle](https://github.com/cbeams-archive/shell-scripts) is super handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've been using:

```
function gradle {
    CURDIR=`pwd`
    NOERR=true
    while [[ ! -e "${CURDIR}/gradlew" ]]
    do
        CURDIR="$(dirname "$CURDIR")"
        if [[ "${CURDIR}" == "/" ]]; then
            echo "Failed to find gradlew in any parent dir. Are you sure this is a Gradle project?"
            NOERR=false
            break   
        fi      
    done

    if [[ $NOERR ]];then
        ${CURDIR}/gradlew $@
    fi  
}
```

find-gradle provides for the possibility of a system Gradle but this one is handy in that it goes in your .bashrc and uses the gradle name.  The looping is definitely cleaner in find-gradle. Might also want to change the error message. The thing about having it in your .bashrc, is that you can rest assured someone won't take your permissions away unless you've lost access to the entire box. ;-)